# Change of coordinates matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My linear algebra textbook has an example that I don't really understand. We're trying to find the change of coordinates matrix from $B$ to $B'$ where $B = \{(1, 1), (1, -1)\}$ and $B' = \{(2, 4), (3, 1)\}$, and the transformation is $T(a, b) = (3a-b, a+3b)$. It says that $T$ in terms of basis $B$ equals
$$
  A =
  \begin{pmatrix} 
    3 & 1 \\ -1 & 3 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

and I can't seem to get that answer. I tried to put the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $T$, and then put those coordinates in terms of $B$, but I couldn't get that, and T(1,1) = (2, 4) which is definitely not (3, -1).

Comment: you can write B' in terms of standard basis vectors.

Comment: I haven't even gotten to B', I can't even figure out how to put to in terms of B.

Comment: you can write B in terms of standard basis vectors

Comment: I figured it out, thanks!

Comment: If you go by your method i dont think you will get the answer

Comment: Can you write your answer

Comment: So let me check it once